# Not asking share your location in worklight hybrid app

Tags: android, google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

The worklight hybrid app is not asking share your location. Without asking it is showing some other location. What can i do for this? Please tell me the solution.

**This is my total code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Go2needs</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;

    function wlCommonInit() {

    }

    function getGeo() {
        alert();
        /* WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(positive, negative, {
                        enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    }); 
                    alert(); */
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          alert('if');
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            //alert(position.coords.latitude);
            //alert(position.coords.longitude);
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            geocoder.geocode({
              'latLng': latlng
            }, function(results, status) {
              alert('geo');
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                  console.log(results[1]);
                  alert(results[1].formatted_address);
                }
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
            });

          });
          alert('end');
        }
      }
      /* function positive(data) {
                        alert();   
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }

                    function negativa(data) {
                            alert(); 
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    } */
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="WL.Client.init({})">
  <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="getGeo()" />
  <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are not making sense. Ask a proper question.

Comment: Isn't it proper question? Idan

Comment: This is not the structure of a worklight applications; you have changed it and put wlcommoninit inside the head of the index.html - put it back to where it was, in its own file, and reference that file in the head, like it was before. Then provide a project to download and debug.

Comment: You also have body onload="WL.Client.init". Why?! What is your Worklight version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are implementing this is very strange; it is as if you're following tutorials from Worklight 4.x or 5.x... very old.

Try this:

**AndroidManifest.xml**
Add required permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**index.html**
The `head` should be like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
</head>
```

And the `body`:

```
<body style="display: none;">
    <h1>Googlel Maps - show my position</h1>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
```

**main.js:**

```
var myLat;
var myLong;

function wlCommonInit(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPositionCoords, errorSettingCoords);

    var mapOptions = {

            center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong),
        map: map,
        title:"Hey Me!"
        });
}

function setPositionCoords(position) {
    myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    myLong = position.coords.longitude;
}

function errorSettingCoords() {
    alert ("Failed setting coordinates.");
}
```

Comment: Whatever code we have written in the wlCommonInit() function is not working why?

Comment: Likely because of your project structure, which does not follow the expected project structure in a MobileFirst project. Who told you to put WL.Client.init on the body element?

Comment: ok it's working wlCommonInit() function after changing..thank u

Comment: but map is not showing and not asking share your location for above code...why?

Comment: This code is meant to be run in a physical device, not preview.